# How sum format strings in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have array string format (hh.mm)
How sum ?
I use extensions:

```
static class SumExtensions
{
    public static String Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, String> selector)
    {
        return source.Select(selector).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
    }
}
```

but I do not understand where parse string and sum

Comment: what do you mean by sum? Do you mean concatenate so "12.12", "11.11" becomes "12.12,11.11"?

Comment: Or by "sum" you mean "01.00"+"01.00" = "02.00" (as in `TimeSpan`s) ?

Comment: The Objects should represent proper structure. So instead of having data in hh:mm format create a wraper tha will parse that to time. Or number of minutes.

Comment: Or by "sum" you mean "01.00"+"01.00" = "02.00" - Yes. But how this create in linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to convert the `string` to the `TimeSpan` representation.
It is necessary because the `TimeSpan` representation allows to perform arithmetic operations for time intervals.

```
string[] timeSpanStrings = new[]
    {
        "01.00", "02.00"
    };

var timeSpans = timeSpanStrings.Select(t => TimeSpan.ParseExact(t, @"hh\.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
var sumTimeSpan = timeSpans.Aggregate((t1, t2) => t1.Add(t2));
```

The variable `sumTimeSpan` contains the result.

Comment: Please read about formaters. You converter to TimeSpan is really poor.

Answer (score 0):

You should first change the data  structure, from String to [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Then you can just simply use function [TimeSpan#add(Timespan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx) to sum the values in your array.

Comment: Yes yes, I need this use in linq

Comment: @simply denis You already have proper LINQ extention in your question. Only thing is that you have to change the format and instead of t1 + t2, use t1.add(t2).